# How to exclude hidden variables from createRange object

Tags: javascript, jquery

As mentioned in the Question, How can i exclude hidden elements from the document range object. With the below code I can create entire body text range. But I want to exclude hidden elements

```
document.body.createTextRange()
```

I am experimenting with the below code

```
$(':hidden').blur();
document.body.createTextRange()
```

But it does not work for me.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you want to do with your TextRange?

Comment: @tim down Thanks Tim.. I am using one of your functions to search text in web browser. I am trying to highlight duplicate elements with red color. This is giving me unwanted results if there are hidden elements with same text. Sometimes my HTML may contain two elements one is hidden and another is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Like a DOM Range, a `TextRange` represents the portion of an HTML document between two boundary points. If you want to represent a portion of the document omitting certain elements, you will need multiple `TextRange`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not()` filter:

```
$(':input:not(:hidden)')
```

I don't know what .createTextRange() does, but if you only want textboxes, and textareas, you can use:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="textarea"]')
```